# SharePoint (lists) - Multiline clamping (display only the first line)

Tags: json, list, sharepoint, multiline, truncation

I have a column that contains multiline data and I am trying to keep only the first line visible and hide the rest so I can have a nice displayed list with minimum gap between the lines. Ideally a JSON script to customize the column formatting. I tried to keep only a certain number of characters visible, works but then again the problem is that when you open the record, the information in that multiline field is not showing but only the number of characters we limited to be displayed in the first place.

I was thinking about putting the value of the first line in a different column (single line text) and have the rest in a different column, that i can just hide. but when i hide that column, i am not able to use my power automate flow as it detects that it is not available (...) if i can get that to work then my problem is resolved.

Appreciate everyone's inpu

Comment: could you use the extra column, include the multiline column in the view, but use Json formatting to set it to `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`?? That way the column would be available for the workflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very helpful tip!!! This made the content hidden (which helped with the spacing between records, so great!!) but the column still shows (the column name/title) any way i can have it hidden too ? Thanks a million teylyn

Comment: Well, you could always use a different view for PowerAutomate. When you use a Get Items command, you can set which view it should use, which will then determine which columns it can see.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on setting the view, I don't think I have ever done it before. Any step by step would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function to hide a part of the multiline. We can only show or hide the whole item in the column. SharePoint will display top 5 lines and hide the others as default.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the comment: Power Automate does not have to work with the view that the user sees in the SharePoint browser interface. You can create a new view in SharePoint and include only the columns you need for the workflow. Give the view a nice, descriptive name.

Then, in Power Automate you can use the Get Items command and under **Advanced options > Limit Columns by View** specify which view you want to use to return the list items. In the screenshot, I'm using a view I called `wfView`. This will return the columns of that view, plus some of the SharePoint default fluff.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Teylyn, as i have never worked with sharepoint or power automate this definitely helps a lot, i only used the new view option since it suits perfectly my needs (in power automate i'm using Create item, so i dont know if i need to use Get items. I think I will just share the link with the users ( or can they select the full list view? ) to this new view with only the limited number of columns.